# Filter Dataframe Based on Differnce Between Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am working on the following dataframe, `df`:

```
name         val_1       val_2      val_3

AAA           20         25          30       
BBB           15         20          35
CCC           25         40          45
DDD           20         20          25
```

I need to keep only that name where any `val` column increase by more than 10 from the previous `val` column. If one column increases by less than 10 from the previous column or doesn't even increase, we need to drop that name.

Desired output:

```
name

BBB #val3 increases by 15  
CCC #val2 increases by 15
```

What would be the smartest way of doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the first value of `val_3` be 25?

Answer (score 2):

```
subset = df[df.filter(like='val_').T.diff().gt(10).any()]
```

Output:

```
>>> subset
  name  val_1  val_2  val_3
1  BBB     15     20     35
2  CCC     25     40     45
```

Comment: Hi @user17242583, thank you such a nice explanation. The value 20 or 30 wouldn't be a problem, considering if the consecutive columns increase by 10 or not.

Comment: Ah I see @Roy, so BBB is selected by 35 (`val_3` of `BBB`) is 15 greater than 20 (`val_1` of `AAA`)?

Comment: Or is BBB selected because `val_3` of BBB is 15 greater than `val_2` of BBB?

Comment: @Roy please check my answer again. I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it, you want to keep the two rows when they have a difference of at least 10 on all columns.

For this, you need to build a mask with `diff`+`ge`+`all` and combine the mask with its `shift`:

```
m = df.filter(like='val_').diff().ge(10).all(1)
out = df[m|m.shift(-1)]
```

output:

```
  name  val_1  val_2  val_3
1  BBB     15     20     35
2  CCC     25     40     45
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, thank you for your respond. Appreciate. I meant If 2 next-to-next columns increase by 10 or not.

Comment: @Roy then your question is unclear, for BBB the increase between val_1 and val_2 has not a sufficient increase (only 5)

Comment: Sorry for that @mozway. I meant, for BBB, val_3 increases by 15 from val_2

Comment: so it's not a consecutive increase (in the sense that all increase at least from 10), so what's wrong with the other answer? You should accept it if it works for you ;)

Comment: Hi @mozway, I'm still not sure about the `all()`. I updated the problem a little: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70340973/filter-dataframe-based-on-differnce-between-columns-not-next-to-next-columns