# Filter Dataframe Based on Differnce Between Columns [Not Next-to-Next Columns]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a unique dataframe, `df`:

```
name         val_1       val_2      val_3     val_4

AAA            1          2           3         11       
BBB            2          3           5         9
CCC            6          4           15        10
```

I need to keep only that name where any right-side `val` column increases by 10 from any of the previous `val` columns, otherwise drop them.

I know that `diff()` and `ge()` would be helpful here, but not sure how they would work if the difference isn't about between next-to-next column.

**Desired output:**

```
name

AAA #val_4 increases by 10 from val_1  
CCC #val_3 increases by 11 from val_2
```

What would be the smartest way of doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure, you don't need to create a column first and then filter the data (but I don't know how at the moment), but I guess the `df.apply` combined with `max(x) - min(x)` is a good way to go here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'name' : ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
        'val_1' : [1,2,6],
        'val_2' : [2,3,4],
        'val_3' : [3,5,15],
        'val_4' : [11,9,10]
    }
)

df.set_index('name', drop=True, inplace=True)
df['rows_to_keep'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[-1] - x[0], axis=1)
df = df[df['rows_to_keep'] >= 10]
```

Comment: Hi @Rabinzel, thank you for your inputs. One concern  -- the `min` val column has be on the left side, and the `max` val column has to be on the right side.

Comment: Then you don't even need the `max` and `min` . Replace it with `lambda x: x[-1] - x[0], axis=1`

Comment: I changed it in my solution. If it is always the last column where the max value should be you can go with x[-1]....or you just replace -1 with the index of the column you want

Comment: It doesn't has to be the last column. We're gonna take the difference only if the max value column is on the right side of min value column.

Comment: I guess then it is my solution a good way to go right ?

Comment: @Roy, if the second value of val_1 was 20, "BBB" would still be removed, correct?

Comment: Yes @fdireito. The right-side column should increases from the left-side column.

Comment: in apply axis=1 means, that the lambda function applies something row by row (on each column if you want). so in this case, you can access each column with lambda x: x[0, x[1]... x[5] and so on.

Comment: if you like my answer, please accept it or give it an upvote, it helps my reputation. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would drop any numbers to the right of the max number per row, and then take the diff between the min/max and look for rows > 10

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x[0:x.idxmax()+1]).max(1) - df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x[0:x.idxmax()+1]).min(1) >= 10].name.tolist()
```

Output

```
['AAA','CCC']
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Finding this error: `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is doing what is required. Notice that I changed the second value of val_1 to 20, so that we can ensure we are not getting differences from left to right, instead of only right to left.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'name': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
        'val_1': [1, 20, 6],
        'val_2': [2, 3, 4],
        'val_3': [3, 5, 15],
        'val_4': [11, 9, 10]
    }
)

df = df.set_index("name")

f = lambda x: max( [ x[:i][-1] - min(x[:i][:-1]) for i in range(2,len(x)+1)] )

df = df[df.apply(f, axis=1) >= 10]

print(df.index.to_list())
```

Comment: Hi @fdireito, finding this error: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: I have about 8000 value columns; however, it works if I reduce the column size to 5-10 @fdireito

Comment: Updated with a new function, that does the job for the sample data set, without recursion (actually, this should have been the initial function anyway).